# Are there any object detection datasets with the same format as PASCAL VOC?

Tags: dataset, data

I was wondering if there are any object detection datasets that have the same format as the PASCAL VOC dataset. Furthermore I would be specifically looking for satellite imagery datasets in that regard but anything would be fine.

Comment: Try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/